# Powershell NotSpecified (:) Continueexception. Errorhandling not working

Tags: powershell, logging, error-handling, active-directory

I seem to have a Problem in my Code so i built a catch block to get a detailed error. That for some reason is also not working. Can you guys help me spot the mistake? Why is my final catch block not logging any error details?

I am using Powershell v5 on a WS2012.

EDIT: I added `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of the Script and changed `Get-Error` to `$_.Exception.Message` Still no trace of an error in the log.

The Error i get in the Console is:

```
Get-ADUser : System error.
At C:\Users\test\Documents\Skripts\replace_umlaute.ps1:10 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -properties $paramlist | Sel ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ContinueException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.Management.Automation.ContinueException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

The Problem is that if the Script encounters a User with an empty `displayName` it just stops and doesn't continue with the next user.

Thank You

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -properties $paramlist | Select-object $paramlist |
foreach{
    try{
    if([bool]$_.sAMAccountName -And $_.displayName -match "[üäßöÜÄÖ]"){
       $aux = [regex]::Replace($_.displayName,'[äöü](?:(?=ß)|\p{L})?',{ 
        param($m) 
        ([string] $m.Value[0]).Normalize('FormD')[0] +
          $(if ([char]::IsUpper($(if ($m.Value[1]) { $m.Value[1] } 
          else { $m.Value[0] }))) { 'E' } 
          else { 'e' }) + $m.Value[1]
        },'IgnoreCase'
    )  
            $dnp = $aux -creplace '(?<=\p{Ll})ß','ss' -creplace '(?<=\p{Lu})ß','SS'
                  

            if(!($_.displayNamePrintable -ceq $dnp))
            {
                $dp = $_.displayName
                try{
                Set-ADUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Replace @{displayNamePrintable=$dnp}
                
                "`r$(Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy - HH':'mm':'ss") [$dp] displayNamePrintable of User $($_.cn) updated to $dnp`r" | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8                
                
                }catch{
                "`r" | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
                $_.Exception.Message | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
                "`r" | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
                continue
                       }
            }
         
      }else{
        continue
        }
        }catch{
           "`r" | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
           $_.Exception.Message | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
           "`r" | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8
        }
}
```

Comment: To catch also non-terminating errors in a try-catch, you need to append `-ErrorAction Stop` to the cmdlets that can throw exceptions, OR set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the start of the script. Also, with Powershell v5 there is no [Get-Error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error?view=powershell-7); that was added in version 7, so better use `$_.Exception.Message` inside the catch blocks

Comment: As said, you need PowerShell 7.x to have the `Get-Error` cmdlet and you say you're using version 5.. Also, no, it won't stop the script unless you tell it to do so inside the catch block. Instead of `Get-Error | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8` do `$_.Exception.Message | out-file $log -Append -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: made the changes but still no error in the logs

Comment: I still don't see `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` on top of the script. BTW, is `$log` a valid path to a log file? It would help if you would **indent** your code properly. Now it is extremely hard to read

Comment: i deleted the `continue` above the last catch block and the errors disappeared. the `continue` was placed after the first `if{}` inside `foreach{}`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments, I also believe you can do with using just one `try{}..catch{}` instead of two.

I also would use `Add-Content` instead of `Out-File -Append`, but that may be a personal preference of mine.
Why enclose all log lines in between `` "`r" `` line feeds? A Windows Newline is CRLF, so `` "`r`n" ``..

```
$paramlist = 'DisplayName', 'displayNamePrintable'
$log       = 'X:\Somewhere\DisplayNameChanges.log'  # path 'X:\Somewhere' must exist

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OUpath -Properties $paramlist | ForEach-Object {
    $user = $_  # capture for when we maybe enter the catch block later
    if ($user.DisplayName -match "[üäßöÜÄÖ]") {
        $aux = [regex]::Replace($user.displayName,'[äöü](?:(?=ß)|\p{L})?',{ 
            param($m) 
            ([string] $m.Value[0]).Normalize('FormD')[0] +
                $(if ([char]::IsUpper($(if ($m.Value[1]) { $m.Value[1] } else { $m.Value[0] }))) { 'E' } else { 'e' }) + $m.Value[1]
            },'IgnoreCase'
        )  
        $dnp = $aux -creplace '(?<=\p{Ll})ß','ss' -creplace '(?<=\p{Lu})ß','SS'             

        if (!($user.displayNamePrintable -ceq $dnp)) {
        
            $dp = $user.DisplayName
            try{
                $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{displayNamePrintable = $dnp} -ErrorAction Stop
                $msg = "`r`n$(Get-Date -Format "dd.MM.yyyy - HH':'mm':'ss") [$dp] displayNamePrintable of User $($user.Name) updated to $dnp`r`n"
                $msg | Add-Content -Path $log -Encoding UTF8                
            }
            catch{
                # $_ now represents the actual error object
                $msg = "`r`nError setting the displayNamePrintable of User $($user.Name): $($_.Exception.Message)`r`n"
                $msg | Add-Content -Path $log -Encoding UTF8
                Write-Warning $msg.Trim()
            }
        }       
    }
}
```